# Navigation in react-native error with stackNavigation

Tags: react-native, navigation, stack-navigator

in the application I am creating I have set up bottom-tabs. They are functioning properly.

```
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Tab.Navigator initialRouteName="Feed"
                     tabBarOptions={{activeTintColor: '#F78400'}}>
        <Tab.Screen
          name="Authentication" component={Authentication}
          options={{
              tabBarIcon: ({ focused, horizontal, tintColor }) => {
                return (
                  <Image
                    source={require("./assets/images/authentication.jpg")}
                    style={{ width: 20, height: 20 }}
                  />
                );
              }
          }}
        />
        <Tab.Screen
          name="Dashboard"
          component={Dashboard}
          options={{
            tabBarIcon: ({ focused, horizontal, tintColor }) => {
              return (
                <Image
                  source={require("./assets/images/dashboard.png")}
                  style={{ width: 20, height: 20 }}
                />
              );
            }
          }}
        />
        <Tab.Screen
          name="Tools"
          component={Tools}
          options={{
            tabBarIcon: ({ focused, horizontal, tintColor }) => {
              return (
                <Image
                  source={require("./assets/images/tools.png")}
                  style={{ width: 20, height: 20 }}
                />
              );
            }
          }}
        />
        <Tab.Screen
          name="Settings"
          component={Settings}
          options={{
            tabBarIcon: ({ focused, horizontal, tintColor }) => {
              return (
                <Image
                  source={require("./assets/images/settings.png")}
                  style={{ width: 20, height: 20 }}
                />
              );
            }
          }}
        />
      </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

So now, I want to set up navigation to be able to go from one screen to another. I added the code of the stacks to the code of my tabs and when I want to go on antorher screen, I click a button to go on another screen, the name of the screen appear at the top of the page but it looks like it still the first screen. I don't get what's wrong

> **view config getter callback for component,**

could you please explain to me how to do? Thanks a lot.

```
import React from 'react'
import { Image } from 'react-native'
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs'
import { createStackNavigator} from "@react-navigation/stack"
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native'
import Authentication from '../../Screens/Authentication'
import Login from '../../Screens/Authentication'
import Signup from '../../Screens/Authentication'
import Tools from '../../Screens/Tools'
import Dashboard from '../../Screens/Dashboard'
import Settings from '../../Screens/Settings'
import Scan from '../../Screens/Tools'
import i18n from '../../src/i18n'

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();
const Stack = createStackNavigator();

function ScreenNavigator() {
  return(
<Stack.Navigator>
  <Stack.Screen name = 'Authentication' component = {Authentication}/>
  <Stack.Screen name = 'Login' component = {Login}/>
  <Stack.Screen name = 'Signup' component = {Signup}/>
  <Stack.Screen name = 'Tools' component = {Tools}/>
  <Stack.Screen name = 'Scan' component = {Scan}/>
  <Stack.Screen name = 'Dashboard' component = {Dashboard}/>
  <Stack.Screen name = 'Settings' component = {Settings}/>
</Stack.Navigator>
  )
}

export default function AppNavigation() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Tab.Navigator initialRouteName="Feed"
                     tabBarOptions={{activeTintColor: '#F78400'}}>
        <Tab.Screen
          name={i18n.t("app.auth")}
          component={ScreenNavigator}
          options={{
              tabBarIcon: ({ focused, horizontal, tintColor }) => {
                return (
                  <Image
                    source={require("../../assets/images/authentication.jpg")}
                    style={{ width: 20, height: 20 }}
                  />
                );
              }
          }}
        />
        <Tab.Screen
          name={i18n.t("app.dash")}
          component={Dashboard}
          options={{
            tabBarIcon: ({ focused, horizontal, tintColor }) => {
              return (
                <Image
                  source={require("../../assets/images/dashboard.png")}
                  style={{ width: 20, height: 20 }}
                />
              );
            }
          }}
        />
        <Tab.Screen
          name={i18n.t("app.tools")}
          component={Tools}
          options={{
            tabBarIcon: ({ focused, horizontal, tintColor }) => {
              return (
                <Image
                  source={require("../../assets/images/tools.png")}
                  style={{ width: 20, height: 20 }}
                />
              );
            }
          }}
        />
        <Tab.Screen
          name={i18n.t("app.settings")}
          component={Settings}
          options={{
            tabBarIcon: ({ focused, horizontal, tintColor }) => {
              return (
                <Image
                  source={require("../../assets/images/settings.png")}
                  style={{ width: 20, height: 20 }}
                />
              );
            }
          }}
        />
      </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  )
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not passing components when initializing the navigation

The below code

```
 <Stack.Screen name = 'Authentication' component = 'Authentication'/>
```

You have passed a string for component which is causing the error, this should change to

```
 <Stack.Screen name = 'Authentication' component = {Authentication}/>
```

You will have to change other screens in the stack as well

Comment: Thanks a lot, the error is corected but I still have a problem navigating. For example when I click a button to go on another screen, the name of the screen appear at the top of the page but it looks like it still the first screen. I don't get what's wrong.

Comment: why do you have the stack navigator and the tab navigator inside the navigation container? even though it wont show an error we only place one at a time

Comment: I have corrected it, I am modifying my post with your help and the modifications.

Comment: i dont see anything wrong with the code above, you navigate from a stack screen to another screen in the stack right and the imports are correct right?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm gonna check if it's not the cache. Thanks again for your time and explanations, you helped me a lot !